# is meta-analysis of combined raw/fully disaggregated data appropriate?

Tags: lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, meta-analysis

I have conducted several experiments that examine Reaction Time as the DV. Because I conducted them, I have the raw data for each.

It makes sense to me that combining all the data (at the single-trial level) provides more information and thus a more powerful meta-analysis, so long as I specify participant as a grouping factor that is nested inside the grouping factor of experiment.

If I were doing this using `lmer` as a  basic multi-level model of nested random effects, I understand I would do something like this:

`Meta_fit = lmer(data, RT~ cond1 + cond2 + (1|experiment/participant)`

Looking at the literature, however,  I cannot find any examples or discussions of including completely disaggregated data in a meta-analysis. I do see a lot of suggestions to use individual participant data meta-analyses instead of study-aggregated data, but even IPD meta-analysis still involves aggregating data at the participant level. I want to include *every trial* for *each participant*.

It seems odd to me that including every trial is not a recommendation when possible? Is there a reason not to include every trial?

Any thoughts or suggestions appreciated

Comment: Good question. I did wonder about some of this multi-level modelling when I switched from psychology to biostatistics. Thinking about this as a multi-level modelling approach might be the most fruitful way forward: what do you gain from including the lowest-level information (and hence variability on an individual-trial level)?

Comment: Presumably what you gain is just that: more information about the variability involved. Perhaps it doesn't matter so much if you use aggregated participant data that is robust/reliable - but I want to examine how RT changes across blocks, and because there are relatively few trials in each block, I don't trust meanRT for each block (single trials might influence the mean too much). Moreover, some blocks will have less trials due to errors etc. It would be nice to take all that variability into account.

Comment: That's roughly what my thinking was back when initially considering this -- though most of the studies I was involved in had dozens or more individual trials (reaction time events) per condition.

Comment: From a pragmatic perspective for exploring the implications of this, I'd consider this as a problem for solving with some kind of multi-level model (at the other extreme you can still think of even aggregate-data meta-analysis being a conceptual type of multi-level model -- passing up the lower study-level variance to the pooled estimate variance)

Comment: ok thanks James. Sounds like we're on the same page - but you would distinguish it from a "meta-analysis"?

Comment: I would describe it as distinct from a *methodological* point of view (i.e. a descriptor of a set of methods) even though the *objective* of your exercise is the same as what we commonly do in meta-analysis.

Comment: I have one more question about using lmer for metaanlysis in this context.  
It seems that lmer is not recommended for meta-analyses because it estimates variance differently than meta-analyses typically do (see refs below). Specifically,  meta-analyses assume sampling variance is “known” at the lowest level, but lmer does not easily allow such fixing… I don’t understand this at all – why is sampling variance assumed to be known in metanalyses, and what does lmer not sharing this assumption really mean (at an intuitive level)?

Comment: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/00273171.2020.1822148. https://www.google.com/search?q=metafor+rma+lmer&rlz=1C1GCEA_enNZ814NZ814&oq=metafor+rma+lmer&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0i22i30l3j69i60l3.3864j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.